# Signal SIGSEGV Caught using sigaction

Tags: linux, signals, handler, segmentation-fault, sigaction

I am developing a multithread application running on linux pc kernel version 4.4.14. I want to track some catastrophic errors causing segmentation fault.
I set up a signal handler linked to SIGSEGV to try to get the pid number of the thread causing the crash. The handler function code is the following:

```
void sighandler(int signum, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context)  
{
    // get pid of sender,
  pid_t sender_pid = siginfo->si_pid;
  printf("Process %d got signal %d SEG FAULT !!!\n", (int)sender_pid, signum);
  fflush(stdout);
  sleep(1);
  printf("Stdout Flushed %d got signal %d SEG FAULT !!!\n", sender_pid, signum);
  trappola.sa_flags = 0;
    trappola.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;
    sigaction(signum, &trappola, NULL);
  kill(getpid(), signum);
  exit(-1);
}
```

and in the main() I link the sighandler function using:

```
struct sigaction trappola;  
memset(&trappola, 0x00, sizeof(trappola));

trappola.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
trappola.sa_sigaction = sighandler;
sigaction(SIGSEGV, &trappola, NULL);
```

the handler is working but I am not able to get the pid of the thread causing the fault. The printf:

```
printf("Process %d got signal %d SEG FAULT !!!\n", (int)sender_pid, signum);
```

always print different numbers as sender_pid none of which are meaningful.
Why I cannot get the pid of the offending thread ?

Where I am wrong ? How can I get the pid of the offending thread in the handler function ?

Thank you very much for any help.

Regards.

Marco Bisio

Answer (score 0):

`siginfo->si_pid` is not meaningful because the thread causing the SIGSEGV (at address `siginfo->si_addr`) is the same thread that receives the signal.

See [the signal(7) manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html):

> A signal may be generated (and thus pending) for a process as a whole
>   (e.g., when sent using kill(2)) or for a specific thread (e.g.,
>   certain signals, such as SIGSEGV and SIGFPE, generated as a
>   consequence of executing a specific machine-language instruction
>   **are thread directed** (...)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Be patient but the thread trowing sigsegv seems to me to be no the same receiving the signal within the handler. I mean: the main() install the handler and run the thread using pthread_create....; after that the thread has an own pid number. I expected to be able to read that pid number from the handler using siginfo->si_pid; 

Thank you again

Marco Bisio

Comment: @mrcbis You don't tell us what makes you thing this is not the same thread. Use a debugger (`gdb`) and you will know what causes the segfault.